# Where do the functions 2n^2 , 100n log n, and (log n) ^3 fit in the big-O hierarchy?

Tags: big-o

The big-O hierarchy  for any constants a, b > 0 is;
O(a) ⊂ O(log n) ⊂  O(n^b) ⊂ O(C^n).

I need some explanations, thanks.

Comment: I can't give you an actual answer, but I can tell you that when we do BigO we negate all constants. So 2n^2 = n^2, and 100nlogn is just  nlogn. logn ^ 3 I'd have to think about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading constants don't matter, so `O(2n^2) = O(n^2)` and `O(100 n log n) = O (n log n)`.

If `f` and `g` are functions then `O(f * g) = O(f) * O(g)`.  Now, apparently you are ok accepting that `O(log n) < O(n)`.  Multiply both sides by `O(n)` and you get `O(n) * O(log n) = O(n * log n) < O(n * n) = O(n^2)`.

To see that `O((log n)^3)` is less than `O(n^a)` for any positive `a` is a little trickier, but if you are willing to accept that `O(log n)` is less than `O(n^a)` for any positive `a`, then you can see it by taking the third root of `O((log n)^3)` and `O(n^a)`.  You get `O(log n)` on the one side, and `O(n^(a/3))` on the other side, and the inequality you are looking for is easy to deduce from this.

Answer (score 0):

you can think about that number that a function produces, it usually goes that the smaller the number, the faster the algorithm is. And if it is a larger number the function produces its slower.

log 10 < 10^b < C^n